# Looking for Flink startup hook/initialization listener to recover the broadcast state?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm looking to run some custom code every time Flink cluster/node restarts.
That custom snippet of code will recover the broadcast state, which is, unfortunately, not backed by RocksDB.

> No RocksDB state backend: Broadcast state is kept in-memory at runtime and memory provisioning should be done accordingly. This holds for all operator states.

Mentioned here:
https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/broadcast_state/

There is a similar question here, however, I couldn't turn into a solution:
[How could Flink broadcast state be initialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54748158/how-could-flink-broadcast-state-be-initialized)

It feels, that having a **startup hook or listener** is a typical requirement to have.  Am I missing something? Any ideas on how to approach this would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this, but I believe it should work to initialize the broadcast state in the `open` method of your `(Keyed)BroadcastProcessFunction`. And then you can further update the broadcast state while the job is running, assuming you have a broadcast stream supplying updates.

But I don't understand why this is an issue. Although broadcast state isn't stored in RocksDB, it is included in every checkpoint and savepoint (like any operator state), and it is restored during restarts.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I see from your earlier post https://stackoverflow.com/a/62510423/5470436
that the broadcast state  is check pointed, regardless if it's memory based or RocksDB. 
Thanks for that!
However, when I run a Flink with broadcast state example the open function (Keyed)BroadcastProcessFunction is invoked more than once.
Is it invoked once per each node?

Comment: Yes, each task slot will have its own instance of the (Keyed)BroadcastProcessFunction. The open method is called once in each instance. (There is also a close that's called during an orderly shutdown.)

Comment: Many thanks! Your answer was super helpful!